# Unable to apply numeric format to column in moderately large CSV file in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, csv

I have a moderately sized CSV file (195,000 rows.) For some reason, when I try to format a column of numbers as currency when opening it in Excel, it does nothing at all. If I edit the file and leave a smaller subset of rows in the file (10-20 rows,) I am able to format the column.

Is this a known issue with Excel? Of course I can just save it as an actual Excel spreadsheet file and then everything works fine, but I'd like to find out what is going on regardless.

Comment: That does not sound like known behavior. One way it could happen is if there are non-printing characters in the column, but then your subset of rows should have been affected also, unless in the process of editing you removed those extraneous characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a known behavior in Excel.

Excel doesn't let you set up the import for a CSV so you cannot influence it in the manner mnentioned. This is the way the issue is able to exist. If you could, it would never get to the issue.

I'll describe the issue, but do not have the details for doing the thing I mention. It's available on the internet, but I recall it taking some time to come across and I do not have that now. My apologies for that part.

The issue is that when Excel import a file like a CSV it actually looks only at the first 16 records in each column of data in order to decide how to format the column upon import. Yep. 16 records, even with a prospective load of 195,000 rows or a million.

Some good point to that:  in data, often the rows are reasonably representative, and also consider the impact on memory and speed of reading the entire data set and deciding how to import the columns. (I'd take that hit myself, but...)

However, consider an example I came across here a month or two ago in which times were coming in formatted for hours and minutes or maybe it was minutes and seconds. Because the data likely was sorted either in actual fact, or in its method of creation, by time and of course, a minute or two and some seconds were the starting records. Not functional there, eh?

There is a way, and this is the thing to research, to direct Excel to look at as many records as one would like before deciding how to format columns. That's the in-program solution to the issue.

(If Excel let you force the formatting like with a TXT file, it would effectively be letting you control this aspect, but... you know... Excel...)

Other solutions are outside Excel. Things like adding some rows at the start which have the form/material to force the formatting you need. Delete them later. Or edit to move a bunch of rows from the middle to the beginning. That kind of thing. Perfectly fine, relatively easy, but who wouldn't prefer an in-program solution, right?

Excel includes a variety of methods to import things as well as simply opening a CSV file. One of them might suit your need and they seem to allow the necessary control.

By the way, I came across this one looking at issues programs that take their own data and create Excel spreadsheets from it, complete with formulas and formatting, seem to face. Seems some use Excel itself to an extent rather than writing all the programming themselves. Valid, but then they fall victim to the shortcomings of Excel. I mean the features, not shorcomings, of course...

Comment: I had a feeling it came down to the size of the data and potential performance impact. Thank you for your detailed answer.